# Select multiple values for 1 user via PHP from SQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, loops

**EXPLAINATION**

I have table with users and another table where stored certificates with user id's. 1 user can have multiple certificates. I need to select user once and list all of certificates by user id, but I can't achieve It correctly, selecting only 1 certificate for 1 user.

**SAMPLE DATA**

*This very simplified sample data, for reality there are over 150 fields and 5 tables.*

I have following tables:

Users

```
Id   FirstName   LastName 
1    John        Smith 
2    Lisa        Washington
```

Certificates

```
UserId   CertificateName
1        Foo
1        Bar 
1        Something
2        FooBar
2        Bizz
```

**PHP** looks like:

```
$UserID = get_current_user_id();
$GetUserId = $_GET["Id"];
if(isset($UserID)) {    

    $users = $con->prepare("
    SELECT u.FirstName
           ,u.LastName
           ,c.CertificateName          
    FROM Users u
    LEFT JOIN Certificates c ON u.Id = c.UserID
    WHERE u.Id = '$GetUserId'
    LIMIT 1
    "); 

    $users->execute();

    $users->bind_result(        
        $FirstName,             
        $LastName,  
        $CertificateName
    );


} else {
    echo "There is no User ID detected, try to refresh browser.";   
}

<html>
....

    <?php 
    while ($users->fetch()) {
    ?>  
        <div class="grid-item"><?php echo $FirstName; ?></div>          
        <div class="grid-item"><?php echo $LastName; ?></div>
        <div class="certificates"><?php echo $CertificateName; ?></div>
    <?php 
    } 
    ?>
```

**OUTPUT FOR NOW**

If I pass `GetUserId = 1` I got results:

```
John Smith 
Foo
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

It should list all of certificates for specific user.

```
John Smith 
Foo
Bar
Something
```

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

I've tried to use `foreach` loop inside while loop, to get certificates, but in this way It didn't selected any certificates at all. Have you any ideas how can I achieve It?

Comment: Your query seems fine and should return john,bar and something , Why would it return 'Foo'?

Comment: It's good that you are using prepared statements. It's bad that you are wrongly using them.. you should use binds in your queries to avoid sql injections: `WHERE u.Id = :uid` and `$users->execute(array('uid' => $GetUserId));`

Answer (score 1):

This should work, you might have to change the separator in something else that you prefer.

```
SELECT u.FirstName,
       u.LastName,
       GROUP_CONCAT(c.CertificateName SEPARATOR '<br>') AS CertificateName         
FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN Certificates c ON u.Id = c.UserID
WHERE u.Id = '$GetUserId'
LIMIT 1
```

Edit: 
Based on correct comment from @Matei Mihai that you should bind parameters instead of putting them in the query which is sql-injectable

```
$users = $con->prepare("
SELECT u.FirstName,
       u.LastName,
       GROUP_CONCAT(c.CertificateName SEPARATOR '<br>') AS CertificateName         
FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN Certificates c ON u.Id = c.UserID
WHERE u.Id = ?
LIMIT 1
"); 
$users->bind_param('i',$GetUserId);
$users->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    Users usr
INNER JOIN 
    Certificates cert
ON 
    usr.Id = cert.UserId 
WHERE 
    usr.Id = '1'
```

to get this **OUTPUT-1**:

```
Id   FirstName   LastName  UserId   CertificateName
1    John        Smith     1        Foo
1    John        Smith     1        Bar 
1    John        Smith     1        Something
```

Comment: If you want the same result you showed in the POST. **1.** Iterate the result fetched through my query. **2.** Create another array in PHP and build the logic to store the fetched result in your desired format. **Note:** This way you'll have to call the database once( which sounds efficient )

Answer (score 0):

The output setup you have would output a multiple copies of John Smith, like so:

```
John Smith 
Foo
John Smith
Bar
John Smith
Something
```

If what you want is

```
John Smith 
Foo
Bar
Something
```

Then you need to either read your query into an array first before output:

```
<?php 
    $certArray = array();
    while ($users->fetch()) {
        $certArray[] = $CertificateName;
    }
?>
        <div class="grid-item"><?php echo $FirstName; ?></div>          
        <div class="grid-item"><?php echo $LastName; ?></div>
<?php
    foreach($certArray as $CertificateName) {
?>
        <div class="certificates"><?php echo $CertificateName; ?></div>
<?php 
    } 
?>
```

Or break it up into 2 queries, which I'll leave for someone else to explain if you need it.

Comment: Thank you for an answer, It worked If I'm trying to select only `$CertificateName` from Certificates table. If I join CertificatesDetails table and trying to select `$CertificateNo` in following:     `foreach($certArray as $CertificateName) {
?>
        <div class="certificates"><?php echo $CertificateName; ?></div> <div class="certificates"><?php echo $CertificateNo; ?></div>

<?php 
    }` I got repeating the same `CertificateNo` for each `CertificateName`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. I used structured programming and mysqli syntax, but I'm sure you can work with that.

```
<?php
 //Assuming $con is your DB connector

$q = 'SELECT * FROM Users';
$r = mysqli_query($con, $q);

while($list = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) { ?>  
  <tr>      
    <td><?php echo $list['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $list['FirstName']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $list['LastName']; ?></td>        
    <td>
    <?php 
    //echo the certificate names            
    $userId = $list['id'];                              

        $q1 = 'SELECT * from Certificates WHERE UserId = '.$userId.'';
        $r1 = mysqli_query($con, $q1);

        while($certif = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r1)){   

            echo $certif['CertificateName'].'<br /> ';          
        }               
?>
    </td>
 </tr>

<?php }?>
```